# localhost xampp is not working

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Dear All Please help me to fix this problem! I have installed xampp 5.6.12 on windows 7 ultimate .I cant'find the "localhost/xampp/"
when ever i try it shows  "http://localhost/dashboard/"
why ??? and I can show the page "http://localhost/phpmyadmin" also, several times i uninstall and install this "xampp" still its same , so i change c:xampp\apache\conf\httpd "ServerName localhost:8080" to( 80, 8800,8080) none of this work so some one please help me !!!
thank you???

Answer (score 0):

That sounds exactly right. What is not working for you? If you want to install wordpress at your local host, feel free to do so. You will need to start up Apache and start up MySQL first though. When you have content loaded up in the hard drive XAMPP directory / subdirectory HTDOCS what ever is in that directory can be accessed from browser via localhost.

Download the WordPress Package.  Unzip it in a directory at HTDOCS.  If it were me, I create a seperate folder (wordpress_test).. Prepare a blank mySQL database.  Ensure you write down the login ID and password to the database. You will need that when you first start up WordPress.  Navigate over to `http://localhost/wordpress_test/wp-admin/` in your browser.  Follow the instructions there.  (Note: NO htdocs displayed in the directory path here, even though the directory is actually in use on the hard drive.  Trust me, it just works.)

The fact that the system uses the directory HTDOCS isn't totally intuitive.  But... that is covered in various online tutorials.  ref: `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/run-a-php-program-in-xampp-server`

Good luck with it...

Update: It seems the original question has been modified to remove the WordPress tags, sigh.  So my answer, pushing WordPress isn't applicable to the question as currently asked.  So instead of WordPress install, lets use a simple php file install. Same general answer.  Same tutorial. Same file directory logic. Same XAMPP functioning.